Thread synchronization with semaphore in C
I am working on an assignment which requires me to simulate a bus travelling from Stop A to Stop B over and over again while students can get on and get out of it.
I coded the whole routine of the bus and the students but I can't seem to get them synchronized properly.
As an example of what is working and what is not, here's a sample run of a single cycle of the program with 4 students/threads (plus the bus thread):

As you can see, the bus is initialized at Stop A, the students are created and getting into the bus correctly (student 3 can't get into the bus because of the department rule that says: N / 4 students of the same department can be in the bus at a given time, here N = 4).
When the bus arrives at Stop B, all students in the bus should get off it and go to the university. Here, only Student 1 is getting off the bus.
Here's the student and bus routines:
void* student_routine(void* argv){

    // decrement semaphore by 1
    sem_wait(&semaphore);

    struct student* student = search_node(student_list, (int)argv);

    // if bus is not at stop A or student can't get in then wait
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while(bus->bus_position != Stop_A || !check_department(student)){
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond_A, &mutex);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    // decrease bus capacity for this department by 1 and get student in the bus
    bus->department_capacity[student->department]--;
    stop_A[student->AM - 1] = -1;
    bus_array[student->AM - 1] = student->AM;
    printf(ANSI_GREEN "Student %d is boarding the bus from Stop A" ANSI_RESET "\n", student->AM);
    print_areas();

    // if bus is not at stop B then wait
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while(bus->bus_position != Stop_B){
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond_B, &mutex);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    // get off bus, go to university and study
    bus->department_capacity[student->department]++;
    bus_array[student->AM - 1] = -1;
    university[student->AM - 1] = student->AM;
    printf(ANSI_GREEN "Student %d is going to the University to study" ANSI_RESET "\n", student->AM);
    print_areas();

    sleep(student->study_time); // simulate studying
    printf(ANSI_GREEN "Student %d finished studying after %d seconds" ANSI_RESET "\n", student->AM, student->study_time);

    // after studying, go to stop B
    university[student->AM - 1] = -1;
    stop_B[student->AM - 1] = student->AM;
    printf(ANSI_GREEN "Student %d is going from University to Stop B" ANSI_RESET "\n", student->AM);
    print_areas();

    // if bus is not at stop B or student can't get in then wait
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while(bus->bus_position != Stop_B || !check_department(student)){
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond_B, &mutex);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    // decrease bus capacity for this department by 1 and get student in the bus
    bus->department_capacity[student->department]--;
    stop_B[student->AM - 1] = -1;
    bus_array[student->AM - 1] = student->AM;
    printf(ANSI_GREEN "Student %d is boarding the bus from Stop B" ANSI_RESET "\n", student->AM);
    print_areas();

    // if bus is not at stop A then wait
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while(bus->bus_position != Stop_A){
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond_A, &mutex);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    // go home
    bus_array[student->AM - 1] = -1;
    printf(ANSI_GREEN "Student %d is going home" ANSI_RESET "\n", student->AM);
    delete_node(student_list, student->AM);
    print_areas();

    sem_post(&semaphore);
    
    return NULL;

}

void* bus_routine(){

    while(true){

        printf(ANSI_BLUE "Bus arrived at Stop A" ANSI_RESET "\n" );
        print_areas();

        bus->bus_position = Stop_A;     // go to Stop_A
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond_A);   // signal that the bus arrived at Stop A
        sleep(BUS_WAIT_TIME);           // wait 3 sec for students to get in

        printf(ANSI_BLUE "Bus travelling to Stop B" ANSI_RESET "\n");
        print_areas();

        bus->bus_position = In_Transit; // bus is in transit
        sleep(BUS_TRANSITION_TIME);     // simulate the bus travelling to Stop_B

        printf(ANSI_BLUE "Bus arrived at Stop B" ANSI_RESET "\n");
        print_areas();

        bus->bus_position = Stop_B;     // go to Stop_B
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond_B);   // signal that the bus arrived at Stop B
        sleep(BUS_WAIT_TIME);           // wait 3 sec for students to get in

        printf(ANSI_BLUE "Bus travelling to Stop A" ANSI_RESET "\n");
        print_areas();
        
        bus->bus_position = In_Transit; // bus is in transit
        sleep(BUS_TRANSITION_TIME);     // simulate the bus travelling to Stop_A

    }

}

I understand that the semaphore is not working properly. What can I do to fix it?
Any answers would be appreciated.

Makes no sense to use a semaphore AND mutex+cond var

@ikegami Okay, let's say I get rid of semaphores, I still have the same issue.

ok, good to know you are flexible in what locking mechanism you are using.

Neither sleep() nor pthread_cond_signal() provides any synchronization for the value of bus and its members.  At least one thing you need to do, then, is lock the mutex around modifications to those in function bus_routine.

If bus_routine() is supposed to be a pthreads thread entry point function then it must have a single parameter of type void *. Even if it doesn't use that for anything.

student_routine(), too, must access or modify bus and its members, and elements of global variables stop_A, stop_B, university, and student_list (and any other shared variables I missed) only while holding the mutex locked.  After returning from pthreads_cond_wait(), it should not relinquish the mutex until it has finished all such accesses it needs to perform before continuing with work involving only other data.  Inasmuch as all of its work seems to involve shared data, it may need to lock the mutex at the beginning and not (explicitly) release it until ready to return.

It makes no sense to use a semaphore AND a mutex+cond var.
It doesn't even make sense to use threads since the student threads don't do anything, but ok.
A cond var approach
Threads
Student

Set the student's status to "at origin".
Lock mutex.
Wait to be on the bus. (Optional.)
Wait to be at destination.
Unlock mutex.

Bus

Lock mutex.
While not done,

For each stop in the trip,

Adjust location.
Unload passengers.
Load passengers.




Unlock mutex.

Unload passengers:

For each student,

If they're on the bus and the current stop is the passenger's destination,

Reduce the passenger count.
Set the student's status to "at destination".




Broadcast the cond var.

Load passengers:

For each student,

If they're at origin and the current stop is the passenger's origin,

If there is space on the bus and the passenger is allowed on the bus,

Increase the passenger count.
Set the student's status to "on the bus".






Broadcast the cond var.

Notes
The bus uses cond_broadcast instead of cond_signal to ensure the correct student(s) are woken.
The order in which students are loaded comes down in the order in which you iterate over the students. Making the system "first come, first serve" is easy.

This is a much simpler approach than the one I posted in my earlier, now-deleted Answer. In the other answer, I was letting the student threads debark and climb aboard themselves, but this anthropomorphization greatly complicated the code. The bus thread should be doing that.
