About threads and semaphore (POSIX semaphores)
I want every time a student is created to display who has been created and in which department they study. I'm stuck and I don't know what parameters to pass to printInfo(), do you have any idea? I also provide an example of execution
Output:

Enter the number of students:
5

Student 1 (Math) created.

Stop A: [1, Math]
Bus:
University:
Stop B:

Student 2 (Chemistry) created.

Stop A: [1, Math] [2, Chemistry]
Bus:
University:
Stop B:

....

Student 4 (Math) created.

Stop A: [1, Math] [2, Chemistry] [3, Physics] [5, Physics] [4, Math]
Bus:
University:
Stop B:

and the biggest part of my code is:
...
sem_t semaphore;
pthread_barrier_t barrier;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

int count=0;

enum place{ 
    stopA=0,
        Bus=1,
        University=2,
        stopB=3
};

enum science{
    Math=0,
    Physics=1,
    Chemistry=2,
    CSD=3
};

struct student{
    pthread_t thread;
    int am;
    int time;
    enum place position;
    enum science department;
};
...

void initialize_students(struct student * Student, pthread_t thread, int i){
    Student->thread=thread;
    Student->am=random_number(1000,6000);
    Student->time=random_number(5,15);
    Student->position=stopA;
    Student->department=random_number(0,3);
    return;
}

void printInfo(struct student * s,int num){

    printf("\nStop A: ");
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
        if(s->position==stopA){
            printf("[%d , %s ] ",i,getScience(s[i].department));
        }
    }
    printf("\nBus: ");
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
        if(s->position==Bus){
            printf("[%d , %s ] ",i,getScience((s+i)->department));
        }
    }
    printf("\nUniversity: ");
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
        if(s->position==University){
            printf("[%d , %s ] ",i,getScience((s+i)->department));
        }
    }
    printf("\nStop B: ");
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
        if(s->position==stopB){
            printf("[%d , %s ] ",i,getScience((s+i)->department));
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void * startEvent(void * args){
    
    struct student * s = (struct student*)args;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    
    printf("\nStudent %d [%s] created\n",++count,getScience(s->department));

    sleep(1);

    printInfo();

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);   
}
int main(){
    int NUM_THREADS;
    int i;

    printf("Please enter the number of students :\n");
    scanf("%d", &NUM_THREADS);
        if (NUM_THREADS < 12 || NUM_THREADS > 200) {
            perror("Invalid number of students. It should be between 12 and 200.\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

    pthread_t * thread=malloc(NUM_THREADS * sizeof(pthread_t));

    srand(time(NULL));
    
    struct student * Students=malloc(NUM_THREADS * sizeof(struct student));

    for(i=0;i<NUM_THREADS;i++){
        initialize_students((Students+i),thread[i],i);
    }

    sem_init(&semaphore,0,NUM_THREADS);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);

    for(i=0;i<NUM_THREADS;i++){

        if( pthread_create(&Students[i].thread,NULL,&startEvent,&Students[i]) != 0 ){
            perror("Error trying to create a thread\n");
        }

    }

    for(i=0;i<NUM_THREADS;i++){
        if( pthread_join(Students[i].thread,NULL) != 0 ){
            perror("Error to join the thread\n");
        }
    }
    return  0;
}

place: Represents the places where a student can be found (stops A, B, bus, university).
science: Represents the student's subject of study (Math, Physics, Chemistry, CSD).
thread: the ID of the thread.
am: a random number representing AM (Register Number).
time: length of stay at the university.
position: the current position of the student.
department: his department of study.
random_number generates a random integer within a given range (from min to max)

initialize_students((Students+i),thread[i],i); You pass an uninitialized variable thread[i] to that function.

Is the output you show the expected output or the real output? In which way do they differ? Your printInfo function seems to print information for multiple students. As far as I understand, you want to print only information for one student. Ist that correct?

I saw identical question yesterday. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79156346/thread-synchronization-with-semaphore-in-c

@0___________, that question may be related to the same assignment, but it's not at all the same question.

Was that printInfo() function given to you, or is it your work?  Because even without any knowledge of what it's supposed to do, it looks wrong.  In particular, all the conditions on s->position look like they should probably be considering s[i].position instead.

But if it's your own work, then how can you not know what arguments to pass to it?
